# How can I ensure the Dapper inserts the correct time into an Oracle database?

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime, date-formatting, culture

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now.  I have a C# application that uses a WebAPI application to access an Oracle database.  The WebAPI uses Dapper to handle the CRUD operations.

When I insert a record containing a DateTime into the database, the corresponding DATE column accepts the data.  However, when I retrieve the data, the time on the inserted record has shifted -6 hours.  The `dbtimezone` for the database is `-06:00`.

This is the SQL statement I use to perform the insert:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(RECORDID,  TYPE,  STEP,  LEVEL,  CRTDUSER,  CRTDDATE,  COMMENTS)
VALUES            (:RECORDID, :TYPE, :STEP, :LEVEL, :CRTDUSER, :CRTDDATE, :COMMENTS)
```

The value I inserted into the database was `02/11/2021 07:32:14` but it showed up as `02/11/2021 01:32:14`.

Is this a C#, dapper, or Oracle issue?  How do I sort it out?

Comment: What is the data type of the column in question? DATE? TIMESTAMP? TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE?  TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE?  What is the data type  of the bind variable supplying the value?

Comment: It is a DATE data type.